# Install R package: UScensus2010blk for windows

Tags: r, installation, package, census

Did anyone tried to install R package: UScensus2010blk on your own PC?

I tried to use from UScensus2010:

> install.blk ("windows")

It gives an error saying "Not Available Yet"

I downloaded the package myself (4.2GB!) and tried to install from local and I still get error messages:

- installing *source* package 'UScensus2010blk' ...
  ** data
  Warning in file.copy(files, is, TRUE) :
  problem copying data\montana.blk10.rda to Q:\LCVDJ\R\R-3.0.2\library\UScensus2010blk\data\montana.blk10.rda: Invalid argument

...

(the error message repeats for different states)
...

** help
Error in lazyLoadDBinsertListElement(from, i, datafile, ascii, compress,  : 
  write failed
ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package 'UScensus2010blk'
* removing 'Q:/LCVDJ/R/R-3.0.2/library/UScensus2010blk'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"Q:/LCVDJ/R/R-30~1.2/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "Q:\LCVDJ\R\R-3.0.2\library" "C:/Users/n1304/Downloads/UScensus2010blk_1.00.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/n1304/Downloads/UScensus2010blk_1.00.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Does anyone have any idea why my installation is failed? I'm using R-3.0.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in the census2010 package. The functions install.tract, install.blk, install.blkgrp, install.county, and install.cdp are supposed to check for R version >= 2.11 if you call the functions with the "windows" argument, but they only check the minor version so if you have R version 3.0 through 3.10 they incorrectly report an error.

To work around this error, you should be able to run

```
install.packages('UScensus2010blk', repos='http://lakshmi.calit2.uci.edu/census2000/R/', type='source')
```

instead of

```
install.blk('windows')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install it, and received the same message. It appears to be a problem with all the "windows" installations, as the command `install.blk("linux")` is functional.